# Writing a simple circuit breaker with thread support

Tags: ruby, multithreading, circuit-breaker

I'm looking to extend a the [simple circuter breaker](https://github.com/soundcloud/simple_circuit_breaker/blob/master/lib/simple_circuit_breaker.rb) written ruby to work across multiple thread...

And thus far I manage to accomplish something like this ..

```
## following is a simple cicruit breaker implementation with thread support.
## https://github.com/soundcloud/simple_circuit_breaker/blob/master/lib/simple_circuit_breaker.rb
class CircuitBreaker
  class Error < StandardError
  end

  def initialize(retry_timeout=10, threshold=30)
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @retry_timeout = retry_timeout
    @threshold = threshold
    reset!
  end

  def handle
    if tripped?
      raise CircuitBreaker::Error.new('circuit opened')
    else
      execute
    end
  end

  def execute
    result = yield
    reset!
    result
    rescue Exception => exception
      fail!  
    raise exception
  end

  def tripped?
    opened? && !timeout_exceeded?
  end

  def fail!
    @mutex.synchronize do
      @failures += 1
      if @failures >= @threshold
        @open_time = Time.now
        @circuit = :opened
      end
    end
  end

  def opened?
    @circuit == :opened
  end

  def timeout_exceeded?
    @open_time + @retry_timeout < Time.now
  end

  def reset!
    @mutex.synchronize do 
      @circuit = :closed
      @failures = 0
    end
  end
end

http_circuit_breaker = CircuitBreaker.new
http_circuit_breaker.handle { make_http_request }
```

but I'm not sure about few things ...

- The multithreaded code has always puzzled me hence I'm not the entirely confident about the approach to say that the stuff seems correct.
- Read operation are not under mutex: 
  While (I think, I have ensured that no data race condition every happens between two threads) mutex are applied for the write operation but the read operation is mutex free. Now,  since there can be a scenario where a thread 1 has a held mutex while changing the @circuit or @failure variable but the other thread read the stale value. 
  So, I'm not able to think thorough does by achieving a full consistency(while applying the read lock) is worth a trade-off over here. Where consistency might be 100 % but the execution code as turn a bit slower because of the excessive lock.

Answer (score -1):

it's unclear what you are asking, so i guess your post will be closed.

nevertheless, i think that the only thread-safe-way to implement a circuit-breaker would be to have the mutex around all data operartions which would result in a sequential flow, so it's basically useless.

otherwise you will have race-conditions like

- thread-a starts (server does not respond immediately due to network issues)
- thread-b starts (10 seconds later)
- thread-b finishes all good
- thread-a aborts due to a timeout -> opens circuit with stale data

a version that is mentioned in martin fowlers blog is a circuit-breaker in combination with a thread-pool: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html